# How to find the intersections of a swept sphere with the edges of a triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

How do I find the point where a swept sphere (a sphere moving along a direction normal) intersects the edge of a triangle (if at all)?

A bit of background: I'm attempting to implement a collision detection/reaction algorithm for moving spheres through a triangle soup. I have robust solutions for when the sphere collides with the triangle face or its points, however I can't seem to nail the edge collisions.

I understand how to find ray/sphere intersections, but adapting that for swept spheres is beating me.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the sphere equation?

Comment: @Moti 
For spheres I have: "||x - c||² = r²"
For lines I have: "x = o + du"
I can combine those into a quadratic equation to find ray/sphere intersections, but I'm struggling to adapt that to swept spheres.

Comment: What do you mean by swept sphere? How the sweeping is defined (by you)?